# Copy MySQL database from its files

Tags: mysql

I have a hard disk that MySQL 5 has been installed on it (this hard disk belongs to another PC with Windows XP) and I've connected it to my PC. How can i copy its MySQL data to another MySQL 5 ??

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see an option in phpmyadmin called "Export"

Comment: You could've extracted the data in a dumpfile.

Comment: i guess i can't. because there isn't any MySQL program or service. I just have its file in Program Files folder. not anymore..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. 
Shut down both mysql server. 
Locate the mysql data directory (e.g. /. If your database use myisam as engine you will find for any database a folder. In this folder are the files for each table, indexfiles and datafiles. Copy the folder to the data directory on your pc. 
Start your mysql server.

PS: Check the version of both servers.

Or you can use mysqldump this is an command line utility for mysql. After export copy the export file to your server and use this command: 
`mysql -u<username> -p<password> < <exportfilename>`

Kind Regards